Receiving error : strip exited with code 72 when compiling MAUI project
I recently updated my MacOS to Sequoia and Xcode to 16.1. After I did those 2 updates I have not been able to compile any of my MAUI or Xamarin projects. I am getting the error indicated in the title (error : strip exited with code 72). The full error is below:
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0/18.0.8314/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(3,3): Error: strip exited with code 72:
objc[5867]: Class DVTNetworkDeviceAddress is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDeviceFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTDeviceFoundation (0x10609af58) and /Users/davidrutter/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDeviceFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTDeviceFoundation (0x10b729f58). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[5867]: Class DVTNetworkDeviceARPScanner is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDeviceFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTDeviceFoundation (0x10609afd0) and /Users/davidrutter/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDeviceFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTDeviceFoundation (0x10b729fd0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[5867]: Class DVTNetworkDeviceMonitor is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTDeviceFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTDeviceFoundation (0x10609aff8) and /Users/davidrutter/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Sha (simul_bcfo.MAUI)
I am dead in the water until this issue is resolved. Any help is appreciated.

It means that there are two Xcode on you Mac, please remove the Xcode in Downloads floder, and open Xcode, go to Settings->Locations->Command Line Tools, and check if you select the right path.

That was the problem. Once I removed the version in the Download directory the apps all compiled successfully. Thank you for the help.

Glad you solved the problem, I converted it to an answer, please view the solution.
It means that there are two Xcode on your Mac, please remove the Xcode in Downloads folder, and open Xcode, go to Settings->Locations->Command Line Tools, and check if you select the right path.
